# Angular : how to get the url in auth.guard.ts when clicking on routerLink

Tags: angular

I want to get the URL in the auth.guard.ts file while clicking on the link created by `routerLink`. Please see below my code in `.html` file:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="genre" routerLinkActive="active">Genre</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="category" routerLinkActive="active">Category</a></li>
```

This is my code snippet from `auth.guard.ts` file:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) { 
  console.log('URL = ' + state.url)
  ...
}
```

I can see the URL in console only if I refresh the browser/page. But when I clicking on the links like "Category" or "Genre" as specified above, the console shows nothing.

Below is my routing file:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../_guards/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
  children: [
      {
        path: 'genre',
        loadChildren: () => import('./genre/genre.module')
          .then(m => m.GenreModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'category',
        loadChildren: () => import('./category/category.module')
          .then(m => m.CategoryModule),
      },
  ]
},

]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: could you also share router configuration?

Comment: @LaminooLawrance It would be good if you can mention while file I need to share?

Comment: the routing file you are using [authGuard]

Comment: @LaminooLawrance added the routing file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try adding  canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] in children routes as well as below.

```
children: [
      {
        path: 'genre',
        canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
        loadChildren: () => import('./genre/genre.module')
          .then(m => m.GenreModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'category',
        canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
        loadChildren: () => import('./category/category.module')
          .then(m => m.CategoryModule),
      },
  ]
```

Comment: not working. I clicked on the category link from genre, and no console.

Comment: Remove canActivate in PagesComponent and try

Comment: I added canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] in the individual component routing and it works